# Grindview with imagebutton and rowcommand

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, imagebutton, rowcommand

i know this a frequently asked question, but i cant find the solution. I hope u can help me.
i try ti bind imagebutton controls into a gridview.
i want to handle the data for the row where the button was clicked

my  aspx file looks like

```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1"
                                  runat="server"
                                  ImageUrl="~/Images/deny.png"
                                  Height="45" Width="45" 
                                  CommandName="SelectComment"
                                  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

and the vb file looks like

```
Protected Sub KontaktAnfragen_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles KontaktAnfragen.RowCommand

    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    Dim commentHiddenField As HiddenField

    If e.CommandName = "SelectComment" Then
        rowIndex = Integer.Parse(e.CommandName.ToString)
```

The problem ist that the page does not handle the click. it do nothing.it even does not jump in the RowCommand function

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your code correctly, you need to add `OnClick="KontaktAnfragen_RowCommand"` to the ImageButton.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the "KontaktAnfragen_RowCommand" to the Gridview's OnRowCommand event the image button is in.

```
OnRowCommand="KontaktAnfragen_RowCommand"
```

I just noticed, in your aboove code, should you not be using the `CommandArgument` value instead of the `CommandName` value for the `rowIndex`?

Also I'm not sure you need to use `ToString` but if you do, use `ToString()` instead of `ToString` as it is a method call.

Something like this (included formatting of if statement, etc..)?:

```
if (e.CommandName == "SelectComment") Then
        rowIndex = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument)
```